# Problema com vagrant up - homestead-7 já existe

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Prezados preciso de uma ajuda. Estou tentando instalar o laravel usando o homestead. Segui um passo-a-passo mas não consegui acessar o index.php, então resolvi fazer tudo de novo. Mas quando dou um vagrant up aparece que já existe a máquina homestead-7, mesmo depois de eu a ter excluído com o vagrant destroy.

```
$ vagrant destroy
homestead-7: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'homestead-7' VM? [y/N] y
homestead-7: Destroying VM and associated drives...
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> homestead-7: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
A VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead-7' already exists.
Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing
name, and try again.
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente acessar seu virtualbox com a interface gráfica, deve existir uma máquina virtual lá chamada homestead-7. Delete ela e tente outra vez.

Isso aconteceu comigo e deletando a maquina pelo virtualbox o erro desapareceu.

Answer (score -1):

Use `vagrant global-status` para visualizar todas as máquinas virtuais que você tem configuradas e o estado de cada uma delas:

```
$ vagrant global-status
id       name    provider   state    directory                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2720c15  default virtualbox poweroff /home/giovanni/Vagrant/wordpress    
6c7b42f  default virtualbox poweroff /home/giovanni/Vagrant/wildfly      
384662f  default virtualbox poweroff /home/giovanni/Vagrant/mariadb
```

Daí você poderá usar o comando `vagrant destroy` fazendo referência ao **id** da máquina para removê-la.